# why alert is not display in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, requirejs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I am trying to use require js in angular js project .I am able to show view but issue is that I am not able to get alert on "Login" button click .Actually I show One alert on button click .

Here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/jv79297BZLiJpY66rKAc?p=preview

```
 function ctrl($scope, $state) {

        $scope.login = function () {
          alert("Login is clicked")
        };

    }
```

I think I got error on console that why I am not able to display alert ?

**http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/ng/areq?p0=LoginCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)**

Answer (score 1):

Passing the controller name in the `define` block of file bootstrap.js did the trick :

```
    define(['ionic', 'app', 'route', 'LoginCtrl'], function (ionic, app) {
        'use strict';


            angular.element().ready(function () {

                try {
                    console.log(app)
                    angular.bootstrap(document, [app.name]);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error(e.stack || e.message || e);
                }
            });


    });
```

You can find the updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vtmYAG2d1gmnPjnxovJw?p=preview)

Comment: but it is called by twice