# how to increase the height of contend popover?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to increase the height of content popover in percentage or in px so that footer comes after that .Actually When I increase the height of contend but hotter remain in same position why ?It should be remain after ion-contend or contend or in bottom of contend

here is code pen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waPoMa

```
on button click pop over is display 

<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Ionic Accordion</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

      <p>
  <button ng-click="openPopover($event)">Open Popover</button>
</p>
  </body>
  <script id="my-popover.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-popover-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">My Popover Title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="contendheight">

    <ul class="list" ng-repeat="item in name"><li class="item item-checkbox  my-checkbox-class"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class=""  ></label>{{item.name}}</li></ul></ion-content><ion-footer-bar><button  class="button bar-balanced ">Done</button><button  class="button button-stable ">Cancel</button></ion-footer-bar>
  </ion-popover-view>
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add you class to `<ion-popover-view class="contendheight">`
SEe example here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqObKq

Comment: Thanks for answering can we use requirejs in ionic

Comment: if we can use requirejs than pls anwer this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991374/why-alert-is-not-display-in-angularjs